# Could you teach me the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: meaning

I came across the sentence

"Some men are born to good luck: all they do or try to do comes right– all that falls to them is so much gain–all their geese are swans–all their cards are trumps–toss them which way you will, they will always, like poor puss, alight upon their legs, and only move on so much the faster."

I couldn't understand the sentence "only move on so much the faster". Could you teach me?

Could i ask a question? What do "them" in the sentence " toss them which way you will" indicate? Lucky people or trumps,anything else?

Comment: Literally speaking, "only move on so much the faster" refers to the poor puss (cat) that is unfazed by falling. "toss them" refers to the cards. In context, both refer back to "some men" of course.

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful question!It states some people have all the luck while others are perpetually unlucky.In other words according to this somehow funny quote it is possible not to work hard and yet become luckier.In fact talks about people who describe themselves as lucky.They can achieve everything without trying.Even their failure is a success.
However, in my view,we all know that actually it's their outlook towards things that helps them create the circumstances for luck and their attitude helps them take advantage of it.Luck, it seems, isn't just luck. Instead, it's having a mindset of opportunity.

"Only move on so much the faster":Progress even faster than before